# Unable to receive broadcast from Service

Tags: java, android, android-intent, service, broadcastreceiver

The issue I am having is in regards to receiving a broadcast from a service that is within an android library project.

**Why am I unable to receive the broadcast? does it have to do with all the service/interface logic being in a seperate android library project?**

Here is the broadcast from the service

```
    broadcastReceivedMessage("THE TOPIC", "THE MESSAGE");
```

Here is the method within the service

```
    private void broadcastReceivedMessage(final String topic, final String message) {
/*      handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {*/
                Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent(CALLBACK_ACTION);
                broadcastIntent.setAction(ON_MESSAGE_RECEIVED);
                broadcastIntent.putExtra(TOPIC_STR, topic);
                broadcastIntent.putExtra(MESSAGE_STR, message);
                sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
/*          }
        });*/

    }
```

Inside a class that implements many interfaces, this is where I am registering to listen for a specific intent filter.

```
  @Override
  public void connect(String address, int port) {
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(MQTTService2.CALLBACK_ACTION);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getContext()).registerReceiver(serviceActionReceiver, filter);
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(MQTTService2.BROKER_ADDR_STR, address);
    args.putInt(MQTTService2.BROKER_PORT_INT, port);
    startService(MQTTService2.ACTION_CONNECT, args);
  }
```

Inside an Activity where I expect to receive a callback from the interfaces and get my broadcast

```
  MQTTEventHandler mHandler = new MQTTEventHandler() {

  @Override
  public void onStatusChanged(CommunicatorStatus status, String message) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.e("onStatusChanged", "----------------Status Changed------------");
    Log.e("STATUS: ", status.toString());
    Log.e("MESSAGE: ", message);
    Log.e("onStatusChanged", "--------------------------------------------");

  }

  @Override
  public void onMessageReceived(String topic, String message) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.e("onMessageReceived", "----------------Message Received------------");
    Log.e("TOPIC: ", topic);
    Log.e("MESSAGE: ", message);
    Log.e("onMessageReceived", "--------------------------------------------");

  }

  @Override
  public void onException(String message) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  }
};

mComm.addEventHandler(mHandler);
```

BroadcastReceiver

```
class ServiceActionReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {



    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

      String action = intent.getAction();
      if (action.equals(MQTTService2.ON_EXCEPTION)) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if (extras != null && extras.containsKey(MQTTService2.MESSAGE_STR))
          fireOnException(extras.getString(MQTTService2.MESSAGE_STR));
      } else if (action.equals(MQTTService2.ON_MESSAGE_RECEIVED)) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if (extras != null && extras.containsKey(MQTTService2.MESSAGE_STR)
            && extras.containsKey(MQTTService2.TOPIC_STR))
          fireOnMessageReceived(extras.getString(MQTTService2.TOPIC_STR),
              extras.getString(MQTTService2.MESSAGE_STR));

      } else if (action.equals(MQTTService2.ON_STATUS_CHANGED)) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if (extras.containsKey(MQTTService2.STATUS_CODE)) {
          MQTTService2.MQTTConnectionStatus status =
              MQTTConnectionStatus.parseCode(extras.getString(MQTTService2.STATUS_CODE));
          switch (status) {
            case CONNECTED:
              fireOnStatusChanged(CommunicatorStatus.DISCONNECTED,
                  extras.getString(MQTTService2.MESSAGE_STR, ""));
              break;
            case CONNECTING:
              break;
            case INITIAL:
              break;
            case NOTCONNECTED_DATADISABLED:
            case NOTCONNECTED_UNKNOWNREASON:
            case NOTCONNECTED_USERDISCONNECT:
            case NOTCONNECTED_WAITINGFORINTERNET:
              fireOnStatusChanged(CommunicatorStatus.DISCONNECTED,
                  extras.getString(MQTTService2.MESSAGE_STR, ""));
              break;
            default:
              break;

          }
        }

      }
    }
  }
```

Method called depending on specific intent filter ( onMessageReceived)

```
      private void fireOnMessageReceived(String topic, String message) {
    for (MQTTEventHandler eventHandler : handlers) {
      eventHandler.onMessageReceived(topic, message);
    }
/*    for (Iterator<MQTTEventHandler> it = handlers.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
      it.next().onMessageReceived(topic, message);
    }*/
  }
```

Comment: Is your Service running in a separate process?

Comment: I am not 100% sure, I start the service by calling startService, and eventually it is started with START_STICKY, but I never put it in a seperate thread or anything.

Comment: Have you specified a `process` attribute in the `<service>` entry in the manifest?

Comment: I have the service declared inside the Manifest. It is only declared inside the application project, not the library project. I am able to successfully reach the service when calling connect()

Comment: Oh, actually, I believe this is your problem (provided everything else is correct): `broadcastIntent.setAction(ON_MESSAGE_RECEIVED);`. You instantiate the Intent with `CALLBACK_ACTION`, which is what you're filtering for on the Receiver, but then that line changes the action, and it will no longer match your filter.

Comment: So there is no way to use a general receiver for many different types of actions?

Comment: You can filter for multiple actions on the BroadcastReceiver, but the Intent carries only one action. That's where the problem is; the broadcast Intent, not the Receiver.

Comment: So would I call registerReceiver() for many intent filters?

Comment: It depends on how you want to differentiate between and handle your callback broadcasts. You could just use a single `IntentFilter`, call `addAction()` on it for each action, and in the Receiver's `onReceive()` check `Intent#getAction()`. That's probably the simplest.

Comment: Perfect. You were a huge help. If you want to post an answer I will accept it, otherwise I am going to post the implemented solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the following is causing a mismatch between the Intent being broadcast from your Service, and the IntentFilter set on the BroadcastReceiver.

```
Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent(CALLBACK_ACTION);
broadcastIntent.setAction(ON_MESSAGE_RECEIVED);
```

The IntentFilter is set for the `CALLBACK_ACTION`, and the Intent is being instantiated with that same action, but the second line above is resetting the Intent's action to `ON_MESSAGE_RECEIVED`, causing it to no longer match the Filter on the BroadcastReceiver.

One possible solution would be to add multiple actions to the IntentFilter, and check the delivered action in the Receiver's `onReceive()` method to determine how to handle the broadcast.

For example:

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(MQTTService2.ACTION_MESSAGE_RECEIVED);
filter.addAction(MQTTService2.ACTION_OTHER);
```

Then, in the `onReceive()` method:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    String action = intent.getAction();

    if(action.equals(ACTION_MESSAGE_RECEIVED)) {
        ...
    }
    else if(action.equals(ACTION_OTHER)) {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

You would then instantiate the broadcast Intent with the desired action, and remove the `setAction()` call afterward:

```
Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent(MQTTService2.ACTION_MESSAGE_RECEIVED);
...
```